# Export values form almost 2 twin tables with the following conditions

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I want to make a project for myself and I don't know how to make to export values from almost 2 twin tables with the following condition if stock general quantity =<5 then export id, name, quantity into urgent table my query is this one

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Spital`.`Stoc General` 
(
    `ID Produs` INT,
    `Denumire` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `Cantitate` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID Produs`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SELECT * FROM `Spital`.`Stoc General`;

INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) 
VALUES ('1', 'Clabax', '20');
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) 
VALUES ('2', 'Betadina', '15');
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) 
VALUES ('3', 'Paracetamo', '4');
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) 
VALUES ('4', 'Oxigen', '3');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Spital`.`Stoc URGENT` 
(
    `ID Produs` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Denumire` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `Cantitate` INT NOT NULL,
    `Date Delivery` DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID Produs`)
)
ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **INSERT INTO Statement** that enable you to Insert data into **Specified Columns**

```
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc urgent`
            (`id produs`,
             `denumire`,
             `cantitate`)
SELECT `id produs`,
       `denumire`,
       `cantitate`
FROM   `spital`.`stoc general` 
where  `cantitate`<5
```

Comment: Is working but i need an conditional for checking if the quantity is smaller then 5

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: Did it worked??

Comment: i need some more help if you can

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71502034/i-need-another-way-of-inserting-values-for-not-have-duplicate-values-and-2-how-c with this one